# Printing out multiple rows in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I want to pass in an int value and get back a list of short passwords that are less than this int. I have had trouble modifying the MySQL cursors example: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html. I want to print out the rows with short passwords but any time the result has more than one row PhpMyAdmin just displays "Processing request" indefinitely. What am I doing wrong? Its ruining my Saturday productivity!

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ShortPasswd`(IN `passwordLength` TINYINT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a INT;
  DECLARE b VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT UID, Password
      FROM authentication WHERE CHARACTER_length(Password) < passwordLength;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SELECT b;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ShortPasswd`(IN `passwordLength` TINYINT)
BEGIN

   SELECT UID, Password
      FROM authentication WHERE CHARACTER_length(Password) > passwordLength;

END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You will get rows UID, password directly. as you get from a query when you

```
call ShortPasswd;
```

Comment: This answer is only returning the first row. Do you know how to return all rows?

Comment: Have you tested `SELECT UID, Password
      FROM authentication WHERE CHARACTER_length(Password) > passwordLength;` query's result in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes (As a side note I made a mistake in the less than sign it should be `CHARACTER_length(Password) < passwordLength;`) Anyway if I run the query `SELECT UID, Password FROM authentication WHERE CHARACTER_length(Password) < 10` manually I get 6 rows returned but when I put the same query in a stored procedure I get the first row out of the 6 I should be getting. Do I need to iterate over the rows and print them as I go?

Comment: Where are you running `call shortPasswd`? In Phpmyadmin or in console or trying directly in program?

Comment: It returns all the rows. I have used this stuff many times in my application.

Comment: I was using the Execute button in PhpMyAdmin. I should have been using `call`. When I use `call` I get the relevant rows. Is this a bug in PhpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to modify these lines:

```
...
DECLARE FINISHED BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

...
IF done THEN
  CLOSE cur1;
  LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;

...
END LOOP read_loop;
```

I use the 0/1 instead of FALSE/TRUE, and close the cursor before leave the LOOP.

Comment: If I try that and go to execute the stored procedure I get the following error: The following query has failed: "CALL `ShortPasswd`(@p0);
"MySQL said: #1326 - Cursor is not open